# Why {...window}.Math is undefined?

Tags: javascript

```js
const a = {x:1};
console.log({...a}.x);
// 1

console.log(window.Math);
// Math {abs: ƒ, acos: ƒ, acosh: ƒ, asin: ƒ, asinh: ƒ, …}

console.log({...window}.Math);
// undefined
```

I don't understand why `{...a}.x` evaluates 1, but `{...window}.Math` evaluates undefined.

Comment: Because `Math` is not an enumerable property of `window`.

Comment: Also see `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, 'Math')`: `{value: Math, writable: true, enumerable: false, configurable: true}`

Comment: Thanks, what it takes to make a property enumerable or not enumerable?

Comment: You can check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty for how to change whether a property is enumerable. (Note that if it's not configurable, you can't change it, which makes sense.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `Math` is not enumerable.

The [ECMA-2018 (ES9) specs](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html) is a little hard to read. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) and a [proposal page](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread) stated: `{...obj}` creates a new object for all of `obj`'s (1) own **and** (2) enumerable properties. `Math` is `window`'s own property, but not enumerable:

```js
console.log(window.hasOwnProperty("Math"));
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, "Math"));
```

You can reproduce the situation with an object:

```js
obj = {};

Object.defineProperty(obj, 'x', {
  enumerable: false,
  value: 123
});

console.log(obj);   // Google Chrome prints { x: 123 } but StackOverflow prints {} and Node.js prints {} too
console.log(obj.x);
console.log(({...obj}).x);
```

Answer (score 1):

{...Window} is using the spread operator to make a copy into a new object. Math is not enumerable so it won't be copied to the new object.

You can test it by your self:

```js
const a = {}
Object.defineProperty(a, "prop1", { value: "enumerable", enumerable: true })
Object.defineProperty(a, "prop2", { value: "not enumerable", enumerable: false })
```

Then copy your object:

```js
{...a}.prop1 //"enumerable"
{...a}.prop2 // undefined
```